# Href not working when javascript inside div tag included

Tags: javascript, php, html, tomtom

I included TomTom map to my php page, and included the TomTom code (javascript) into a separate body tag at the very bottom. I'm noticing that when I include the TomTom script within these  tags, none of my buttons (href links) are working.

All of the code is on one sublime text page (map.php).

map.php:

```
<!--Developer code: https://developer.tomtom.com/blog/build-different/add-tomtom-maps-              
website-30-seconds-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Details Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://api.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-for-        
web/cdn/5.x/5.41.0/maps/maps.css">

<script src="https://api.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-for-web/cdn/5.x/5.41.0/maps/maps-web.min.js">. 
</script>

<script src="https://api.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-for-web/cdn/5.x/5.41.0/services/services- 
web.min.js"></script>

<style>

    #map-div {
        padding: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;

    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<ol>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"]));
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $navigator = $_POST['navigator'];

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT stores_name FROM stores ";
    $rs_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($rs_result);

    if ($rowCount > 1){
        echo "There are " .$rowCount. " results...";
    }
        else {
            echo "These is " .$rowCount. " result...";
        }
    

    if ($rowCount > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_result)){  
            $title = $row['stores_name'];
            //$id = $row['stores_id'];

            $href = '<a href="details.php?id='. urlencode($title).'">'.$title.'</a>';
                            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<tr><td>" ."No results found". "</td><td>";

            }      
?>
</ol>
</body>


<body>

<div id="map-div" name="map-div"></div>
    
<script>
    const API_KEY = 'XXX';
    const APPLICATION_NAME = 'My Application';
    const APPLICATION_VERSION = '1.0';

    tt.setProductInfo(APPLICATION_NAME, APPLICATION_VERSION);

    const GOLDEN_GATE_BRIDGE = {lng: -122.47483, lat: 37.80776};

    var map = tt.map({
    key: API_KEY,
    container: 'map-div',
    center: GOLDEN_GATE_BRIDGE,
    zoom: 12
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Invalid HTML. You can only have one `<body>` tag. You should just have `<body>...</body>`.

Comment: I originally had the <div> & <script> tag in the first body tag and I'm facing the same issue, so I made the 2nd <body> tag to see if the issue will be fixed. But at least now I know to only have one <body>